# Transfering progress to my xbox one character

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If I make progress on my Xbox 360 GTA character, is there any way I can update this progress to my Xbox One character?

I was thinking I could perhaps delete the Xbox One character, and transfer the character across from the Xbox 360, again.

Comment: (IF) you still have the ability to transfer characters, the option is a full transfer. That is, you will be receiving the exact character on your Xbox one game. Any extra progress your Xbone character has will be lost.